# How to create toolbar in separate xib file and separate class and use it in multiple view controllers?

Tags: ios, toolbar

How to create a toolbar in a separated xib file and separate class and use it in multiple view controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are asking if it possible to re-use a view created in nib in different nibs or views.

The answer is yes and no: 
You can do it, but you have to do it programatically. 
Let's call the view you want to reuse as `View a`, and the view you want to insert it to as `View B`. You need to instantiate `View A` in code and add it as a subview to `View B`. If you are using XIB file for `View b` as well, you can add a "container view" in that nib file, and add `A` in code as a subview to the container. (giving it the container's bounds).

```
let reusableView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ResuableView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ResuableView
resuableView.frame = self.containerView.bounds
self.containerView.addSubview(resuableView)
```

Comment: Do you mean I can not do it for toolbar directly but I should to use view and inside it the toolbar?

Comment: What I mean is you can't reuse an existing Nib view in another nib. You will need to add it in code.

Comment: the reusable toolbar should be created in empty XIB or view XIB??

Comment: Both will actually work, it depends on how you use it. The easiest would be use an empty nib imo